# "No branch" when installing with composer.json

Tags: composer-php

I've got own bundle "MyBundle" with composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "mybundle",
    "require": {
        "propel/propel-bundle": "1.1.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src\" }
    },
    "target-dir": "MyBundle/"
}
```

When i'm trying to check it out with composer ("mybundle": "dev-master"), everything is ok, but it's on "no branch" branch.

How can i set a branch ("master") for installed bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible due to the way composer installs work, and the fact it needs to be able to install specific versions of a branch. When you do that git ends up in a headless state.

If you need to work inside that installed bundle and push some commits just make sure you `git checkout master` before doing that. If you forgot and committed your changes you can also just checkout master and then merge the changes you did on to it.

**Update:** Composer now checks out branches by name if the commit you checkout matches the last commit of the branch.

Comment: I get that Composer does this for a reason, but when you're doing a lot of work in bundles as part of a team, naturally you find yourself doing `composer update` quite a lot– it would be great if there was a more reliable workaround to having to remember to checkout master first / merge in when you forget. Perhaps a configurable way to define which packages you want to always be on a particular branch and some kind of comparison of the state of the detached head to that branch?

Comment: Maybe we could checkout the branch if it's the same commit as the current reference yes. Can you open an issue on github for that?